# Control SVN access only to add, not modify once added in SVN repo

Tags: svn

Is it possible to give add-new as well as and modify access to a user and only add new file access to other user? In short, other user should not be able to modify anything once he commits a file to SVN. Do we have this type of access control in SVN?

As far as I know it can only be read or read\write. Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: As already mentioned can be done by hook scripts but isn't this contrary to the meaning of a version control tool like SVN ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do such things with the svn [pre-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) scripts.

You could find a good example of [pre-commit hook here](http://wordaligned.org/articles/a-subversion-pre-commit-hook).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, it is not possible.

Long answer: There are a lot of reasons why this approach will fail at the end, here are some of them:

- There is no support at all from Subversion for an authorization like you want it to have. So the pre-commit hook (mentioned in the answer of @Cedric_Julien) should contain all logic and configuration.
- The pre-commit hook is only changeable by a system administrator, so every time you want to configure something different, you have to ask them.
- Every time the user commits a new file, and he has made some fault, he has to contact a different type of user that has modify rights to correct his fault. And even if that happens only with every 100th file, it is not a reasonable process to do that.
- I cannot imagine why that policy could be reasonable, and under which circumstances. Normally, adding and changing files is seen the same way. I don't know any configuration management system that has a such fine grained access control to allow such a thing. So I suspect that it is not reasonable to implement something like that.

Sorry, I don't think you should do that. Perhaps you could add some of the application context, so we could understand why it is reasonable in your situation.